# How to restore grub after deleting it from Windows 8 disk manager?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grubrescue

I deleted 2 partitions from Windows 8 disk manager. It turned out one of them is the grub partition. Now the laptop directly goes to grub rescue mode. I used F12 to select the system I want to boot into, but all ended up in grub rescue. The ubuntu installation CD does not help either.  Does anyone have any idea to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Just boot from the Ubuntu LiveCD, and once it boots up, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Run Boot Repair once the installation is done.

<sup>Source:[Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I was able to boot repair grub. But now I only see windows 8. My ubuntu partition is still there(29.2GB), but I have no way to boot into it. Do you have any idea? I don't want to lose everything in there

Comment: You can still use Boot Repair for that.  See the website.

Comment: Sorry I don't totally understand. I used "recommended repair" option and only windows was repaired. What do I need to select in boot-repair to detect the ubuntu system? Or the ubuntu system is already damaged?

Comment: I'm researching, and will let you know.  In the meantime, take a look at the Advanced Options.  Also take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows).

Comment: I can't even see the files in ubuntu system. The whole partition is empty now. Does this mean that the information is gone?

Comment: Are you using the LiveCD to view the contents?

Comment: Yes. The liveCD can't see anything

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10166/discussion-between-mitch-and-user2390930)